# Problems making radial gradient in arcs using javascript, d3 with data from json file

Tags: json, svg, d3.js, radial-gradients, sunburst-diagram

I'm using javascript and d3 (v6) and working towards making a [sunburst type plot](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8)
or at least a plot with [arcs at different radial distances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekpCK.png) where each arc has potentially its own gradient (a radial gradient from center to periphery). At this point I've followed some examples (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566727), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53854817/2714597)) where I set up a set of radialGradient elements and then use the ids from that to generate the fill in my actual arcs. But I am generating my arcs and gradients from data from a json file, and this makes it different from previous questions because the svg element generation is within the d3.json call (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17294710)).  I have two problems. (1) The gradient setups have lines like:

```
grads.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%").style("stop-color", "white")
        .attr("offset", "100%").style("stop-color", "green");
```

but these don't seem to actually get added to the grads elements (when I look at the inspector in the webpage).
(2) The link to the arcs doesn't seem to work, although perhaps that is because of the first problem.

JAVASCRIPT (can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/evodevosys/stackoverflowdata/-/raw/master/arcExample.js))

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var body = d3.select('body')

// append svg to the DIV
chart = d3.select(".chart");

const svg = chart.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

///////////////////////////////////////  Global variables controlling the arc appearance //////////////////
const arcMin = 30;
const arcWidth = 45.5;
const arcPad = 1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

d3.json('dataExample.json')
    .then(function (data) {

        const grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient").data(data.sequences);
        grads.enter().append("radialGradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            .attr("fr", (d, i) => arcMin + (d.pulse-1) * (arcWidth))
            .attr("r", (d, i) => arcMin + d.pulse * (arcWidth))
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return "grad" + d.code;
            });
        grads.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%").style("stop-color", "white")
            .attr("offset", "100%").style("stop-color", "green");//eventually this gradient will go between two colors that are functions of the data that is read in from the json file

        console.log(grads);

        var arc = svg.selectAll('path.arc-path')
            .data(data.sequences);
        arc.enter()
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', d3.arc()
                .innerRadius((d, i) => arcMin + (d.pulse - 1) * (arcWidth) + arcPad)
                .outerRadius((d, i) => arcMin + d.pulse * (arcWidth))
                .startAngle(function (d, i) {
                    ang = (i * 30) * Math.PI / 180;
                    return ang;
                })
                .endAngle(function (d, i) {
                    ang = ((i + 1) * 30) * Math.PI / 180;
                    return ang;
                })
            )
            .attr("class", ".arc-path") // assigns a class for easier selecting
            .attr("transform", "translate(600,300)") 
            //.style('fill',(d) => `rgb(${d.code * 10},${d.code*20},${255 -d.code * 7})`); this works - but doesn't use the gradients
            .style("fill", function (d) {return "url(#grad" + d.code + ")";})


    })
```

JSONFILE (called dataExample.json above) can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/evodevosys/stackoverflowdata/-/raw/master/d3ArcGradientExample.json)

```
{"type":"sequenceData","sequences":[{"pulse":1,"code":0},{"pulse":1,"code":1},{"pulse":1,"code":2},{"pulse":2,"code":3},{"pulse":2,"code":4},{"pulse":2,"code":5},{"pulse":2,"code":6},{"pulse":2,"code":7},{"pulse":2,"code":8},{"pulse":2,"code":9},{"pulse":2,"code":10},{"pulse":3,"code":12}]}
```

index.html (can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/evodevosys/stackoverflowdata/-/raw/master/index.html))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Gradient arc test</title>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chart"></div>
        <script src="arcExample.js">    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And if there are other problems or bad coding practices you notice, please let me know since I'm new to this.
Thanks.

(edited)

Based on Ruben Helsloot's comment I made some jsfiddles with the various parts.  There are 4 fiddles. They differ in 2 aspects:  (1) how the json file is read in and (2) how the fill is generated. I'll note that for my final purpose I need to be able to read the json file from a file - either local or from a URL 
(1) [jsfiddle Version 1](https://jsfiddle.net/grenblau/bmnofzwa/7/) Attempts to read json from a URL and attempts to use gradients for the fill. I think there is a problem reading from the url as well as a problem with the gradient filling.
(2) [jsfiddle Version 2](https://jsfiddle.net/grenblau/hcy2tLgu/5/) Attempts to read json from a URL but does not use gradients for the fill.  This has problems with reading the URL.  When I do this on my local machine reading the json from a local file, this version does generate an output (although not gradients).
(3) [jsfiddle Version 3](https://jsfiddle.net/grenblau/bsp4o6L3/5/) This puts the json in a local variable called data and then uses that.  It also tries to use the gradients for filling.
(4) [jsfiddle Version 4](https://jsfiddle.net/grenblau/wdv7y0er/3/) This puts the json in a local variable called data and then uses that. It does not use gradients for filling.  This is the only one of the 4 that gives the output on jsfiddle.

Comment: Please turn your code into a runnable [mre], it will help us see what's going on. YOu can host your JSON file on github or just store it as the variable `data` and remove the `d3.json` call

Comment: I edited the post with links to 4 jsfiddles with variants that show the problem.  There is a problem reading from the URL using d3.json.  Ultimately, I need to be able to read from a file or URL instead of having the data in the javascript file itself. I also posted the index.html, arcExample.js, and dataExample.json file at gitlab (links in the question) for local testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn basic SVG 1.1 specification first and then how to add elements (not attributes) to the correct SVG structure.

Below is fixed code though I don't know exactly what gradient do you want to achieve. You can try to change the *gradientUnits* attribute back to *objectBoundingBox* but first experiment with the *r* attribute as well.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var body = d3.select('body')

// append svg to the DIV
chart = d3.select(".chart");

const svg = chart.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .attr("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

///////////////////////////////////////  Global variables controlling the arc appearance //////////////////
const arcMin = 30;
const arcWidth = 45.5;
const arcPad = 1;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var data = {"type":"sequenceData","sequences":[{"pulse":1,"code":0},{"pulse":1,"code":1},{"pulse":1,"code":2},{"pulse":2,"code":3},{"pulse":2,"code":4},{"pulse":2,"code":5},{"pulse":2,"code":6},{"pulse":2,"code":7},{"pulse":2,"code":8},{"pulse":2,"code":9},{"pulse":2,"code":10},{"pulse":3,"code":12}]};

        const grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient").data(data.sequences);
        gradsWrap = grads.enter().append("radialGradient")
            //.attr("gradientUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            //.attr("fr", (d, i) => arcMin + (d.pulse-1) * (arcWidth))
            //.attr("r", (d, i) => arcMin + (d.pulse-1) * (arcWidth))
            .attr("fr", "0%")
            .attr("r", "25%")
            .attr("id", function (d) {
                return "grad" + d.code;
            })
        gradsWrap.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", "white");
        gradsWrap.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%").attr("stop-color", "green");//eventually this gradient will go between two colors that are functions of the data that is read in from the json file

        console.log(grads);

        var arc = svg.selectAll('path.arc-path')
            .data(data.sequences);
        arc.enter()
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', d3.arc()
                .innerRadius((d, i) => arcMin + (d.pulse - 1) * (arcWidth) + arcPad)
                .outerRadius((d, i) => arcMin + d.pulse * (arcWidth))
                .startAngle(function (d, i) {
                    ang = (i * 30) * Math.PI / 180;
                    return ang;
                })
                .endAngle(function (d, i) {
                    ang = ((i + 1) * 30) * Math.PI / 180;
                    return ang;
                })
            )
            .attr("class", ".arc-path") // assigns a class for easier selecting
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")")
            .attr('stroke', 'white')
            .style('stroke-width', '2px')
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
              //return "red";
              return "url(#grad" + d.code + ")";
            })
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>Gradient arc test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Based on your code and the example I based my code on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566727), I also tried removing the semicolon after `const grads = svg.append("defs").selectAll("radialGradient").data(data.sequences)` and going straight into the `.enter().append("radialGradient")...` part instead of adding the additional gradsWrap variable and it worked as well. This clarifies a lot.

Comment: Sure, you just have to distinguish if you are adding the attributes or subelements to one SVG element. In the later case and often requiring several subelements the way to define a "wrapping" (variable) element is practical.